# How sum IG column values dynamically

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using Oracle APEX 22.2. I have an IG based on the SCOTT.EMP table. I need to sum the "SAL" column values whenever any change happens to any value of any cell of the column. I used

```
function(config) {
    config.defaultGridColumnOptions = {
aggregates: ["SUM"]
    };  
    return config;
}
```

and it works fine in case of the table has data. But if the table is empty, then no sum is calculated when I add new rows. Is there a solution for that?